# Declare a variable in the extended blade and get the value in another blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, declaration

How can I get the value that is declared inside the *layout.blade.php* file to another *blade.php*.

Here is my Code which is simplified to make you understand :

*client.blade.php*

```
<?php
$a = '33';
?>
@extends('layouts.layout')
@section('body')
<?php
echo $b;
?>
```

In the *layout.blade.php* :

```
<?php
echo $a;
$b = "hi";
?>
```

What happens is, I am able to print the variable `$a` in the *layout.php* file, but the variable `$b` that is declared inside the *layout.blade.php* is not printing in the *client.blade.php*.

How can I make available of it ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you cant do that. The way the template works, you cant send data "back" the other way. You should declare the variable in your controller, and pass it to both views.

[Or you should use a view composer](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/responses#view-composers), and have the variable automatically assigned when the view is created.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that.
You should use  `View::composer` as suggested or use the `View::share` method that allow you to create a sort of global variable avaiable in all the views you need.

For example you can add a `View::share('user', Auth::user());` in your `BaseController` and use `$user` in all the views rendered by controllers that `extends` the `BaseController`

Doc: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/responses#views